# What's the most used format for webpages for mobile?

Tags: asp.net, mobile, html

It's a very long time since I've looked at anything in the mobile world so I'm very out of touch.  I have a website (done in ASP.Net) that is running live at the moment and I need to make a mobile version of it.

What's the best/most frequently used format of pages to serve up to mobiles these days?  Is it a cut down HTML page with few graphics etc or is it WML or something else?

Types of handsets being targetted could be anything - just what people have in their pockets I suppose.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think some of the smart phones like the iPhone do WML. I would stick to XHTML with small graphics (not merely HTML--XHTML is a must because it is less processor intensive, and you should write good code anyway).

Comment: And are there any generic emulators out there to see what the XHTML page looks like on various devices?

Comment: I normaly do this process: 1) Test with Firefox plugin [1], 2) test with emulator (nokia, openwave, some web simulators) and 3) test in real mobiles [1] https://addons.mozilla.org/es-ES/firefox/addon/1345?collection_id=66e24e77-d0f9-7c24-a2b3-cb9cf8d40d4a

Answer (score 2):

This article might help you alot. It's from Smashing Magazine.

[Mobile Web Design Trends For 2009](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/13/mobile-web-design-trends-2009/)

There is additional considerations to keep in mind when designing for mobile web. [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com) provided an insightful list in [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/designing-for-mobile-web/).

> 1. Don't Mix Up Your Markup
> 2. Know Your Phones
> 3. Target the Right Customers
> 4. Publish the Bare Minimum
> 5. Choose a Great Domain Name
> 6. Validate Your Markup
> 7. Test, Test, TEST!